# Bash: Process numbering with screen and exec

Tags: bash

If I start a screen using `screen -dmS screenname java -jar jarfile.jar`, will the process `java jar jarfile.jar` always have a PID that is one value higher than the screen?

As for exec - if I did `exec java -jar jarfile.jar`, would the process ID of this Java process be one higher than the value of the PID of the shell?

Comment: Is that what you have observed?

Comment: Yes, it is. I just don't know if "always" works here.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to establish the context. Your question didn't quite say whether you're just curious or it was something you observed and were wondering if that is the expected outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. PIDs aren't that predictable. When two processes are started very close to the same time, their PIDs are usually close together, but there's always the chance that another process started at the same time (another user, a cron job, a daemon that spawned a child in response to some network traffic...) and will get between them.

Also, sequential PID allocation wraps around from a maximum value to a low number. Some systems have 32-bit PIDs but I think 16-bit is more common, so the wrap-arounds are pretty frequent, with a max at 32767 and a minimum of about 700.

Some systems have randomized PIDs as a security feature.